# how to scan bar code specific format flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can disable QR code and scan only bar code type in flutter. In flutter bar code it is also scanning QR code then  can  disable QR code scanning

I have tried with scanner package but it is scanning QR code with bar code. I want to scan only qr code

Answer (score 0):

try this package for both QR code and barcode [ai_barcode](https://pub.dev/packages/ai_barcode)